# Mixed Content: The page at was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint. This request has been blocked;

Tags: nginx, deployment, https

How can I implement my HTTPS server using Nginx and have a certificate for the client? The Nest JS server is located on port 5000 via pm2.

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        root /var/www/smartfront/build;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name smartpizza.com.ua www.domain.com.ua;

        location / {
           
                proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:3000;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

       

       
}
server {
        root /var/www/smartfront/build;       
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name domain.com.ua; # managed by Certbot
        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:3000;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        location /api {
      proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:5000;
    }



    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com.ua/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com.ua/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = domain.com.ua) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80 ;
        listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name domain.com.ua;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

I tried to write this:

```
location /api {
      proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:5000;
    }
```

but it didn't help me, the server and the client are on the same domain.
If I put HTTPS in the react application while accessing the server `https://domain.com.ua:5000` it says: `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`